# Can't work out what type of wall my bathroom has

Tags: bathroom, walls, mounting, interior

I want to attach a bathroom cabinet above the sink in the image. The house is a UK terraced new build from 2020. This particular wall is one I share with my neighbour's house. However when I tap it it sounds hollow (all the walls sound hollow to me).

Feeling with my hand, there is a faint bulge about 10cm wide running vertically up from the centre of the sink. These bulges repeat like railroad sleepers every 40cm or so. The studfinder I borrowed beeps at the valleys precisely half way between the bulges, which is sort of the opposite of what I expected, but I also question if I'm using it right as it seems to beep randomly all over (it's a QLUUE Stud Finder 5-in-1).

Most people I've asked advice from have said the only way to know is to drill a small hole and look, but I'm not even sure what I'd be looking for.

Also what wallplugs should I be using? Universal? Butterfly? None of the studs are near where the screws would go. The cabinet is 8kg and has two 5mm holes in the top corners for mounting. What depth should they be?

I know there's a lot of unknowns and I have tried hiring a handyman but the job is so small no one worth their salt is interested.

[image]

Comment: It was built in 2020, so 3 years out you should be able to track down the builder, the plans, or both...your local department that oversees building permits probably has a set of plans on file in a publicly accessible archive, if the builder is not cooperative.

Comment: Experiment with a piece of ferromagnetic metal to test your tester.

Comment: The holes are prescribed by the manufacturer, so you need to prescribe the thing's placement. That placement will layout the holes on the wall for you. I would just pretend that there's framing at that layout and screw away (or span away, is it?), where the process will flag any spots that need your butterfly wallplugs or whatever (assuming, of course, that they haven't flown away while you weren't paying attention). Then you can just ream any scars with the correct sized drill bit for your hollow wall fasteners.

Comment: There's a common mistake when hanging such things where people use a level to make sure it's flat. If the ceiling is out of level and close to your cabinet, then a level cabinet will look out of level. If the shower door is out of plumb and close to your cabinet, then a plumb cabinet will look out of plumb. Etc. Parallel is how you achieve good aesthetics. It might not work out functionally if you're storing a marble collection in there, though.

Comment: 8 kg self mass plus, say, another 30# for a total of 50#. Divide that by two for a load on each anchor of about 25# or about 10 kg. I'd shop for hollow wall anchors to support about 15 kg each. Shameful that after surrendering on the whole metric thing over there, you guys specify kilograms for weight instead of _Newtons._ Didn't the French also invent some goofy 10 day week? One deciweek those French are going to get what they have coming.

Comment: Yours may be different,  but normally you place the stud finder on the wall away from studs efc, then turn it on. This calibrates it. Then turn up the sensitivity till it triggers, and back off a bit. Now just slide it around, dont lift.

Comment: @popham - a Newton is a measure of force, a Kilogram one of weight.

Comment: You're going to want a light too. Now it's worth someone's time. And they'll know all about by the time that's done. Like how if that isn't actually drywall, they should've stayed home too.